# Postfix won't send emails

Tags: email, centos, postfix-mta

Suddenly I broke my Postfix:

I'm running, CentOs, Postfix, Dovecot.

My Postfix main.cf file: http://pastebin.com/STLNRYUK

```
hostname returns snapshop
hostname -f returns snapshop.thoeisen.dk
```

(I think my hostnames could be the problem - But I've tried many things now)

I tried:

```
telnet localhost 25
ehlo thoeisen.dk
mail from: <anon@thoeisen.dk>
rcpt to: <...@hotmail.com>
data
something
.
quit
```

Then this is the log:
my maillog http://pastebin.com/FGLxFBjN (search and replace on each email though)

And the e-mail is not sent to the hotmail address.

(This all happened when I tried to install DKIM, and made the TXT for DNS. which I couldn't make work, so I reverted everything back to normal)

Need any other information just ask - Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/troubleshooting
it helped me before.